# Neural network guesing "3" everytime after being trained

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I'm creating a neural network for handwritten digit detection. At this moment in time im only training it on about 200 digits that ive got off of the internet and processed to be black or white (1 or 0).

When I train my neural network with 10 of these images and test on all 200 I get an accuracy of 61.5% but if I test with all 200 I get an accuracy of 10% because it guesses 3 for everything. Why is this happening. I've tried changing the size of the layers but that doesn't help. I think theres an error with the logic of my neural network

```py
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))

def sigmoidd(z):
    return z*(1-z)


def train(x, y, iterations = 1000):
    synoptic_weights1 = 2*np.random.random((400,12)) -1
    synoptic_weights2 = 2*np.random.random((12,12)) - 1
    synoptic_weights3 = 2*np.random.random((12,10)) - 1



    #print(synoptic_weights)

    for i in range(1000):

        hidden_layer_1 = sigmoid(np.dot(x, synoptic_weights1))

        hidden_layer_2 = sigmoid(np.dot(hidden_layer_1, synoptic_weights2))

        outputs = sigmoid(np.dot(hidden_layer_2, synoptic_weights3))
        #print(outputs)
        #print(answers)

        output_error = y-outputs

        output_delta = output_error*sigmoidd(outputs)

        hidden_error2 = output_delta.dot(synoptic_weights3.T)

        hidden_delta2 = hidden_error2 * sigmoidd(hidden_layer_2)

        hidden_error1 = hidden_delta2.dot(synoptic_weights2.T)

        hidden_delta1 = hidden_error1 * sigmoidd(hidden_layer_1)        
        synoptic_weights3 += hidden_layer_2.T.dot(output_delta)
        synoptic_weights2 += hidden_layer_1.T.dot(hidden_delta2)
        synoptic_weights1 += x.T.dot(hidden_delta1)


    return synoptic_weights1, synoptic_weights2, synoptic_weights3
```

I expect when testing to get a decent accuracy with all the 200 images, not 10%

Comment: Nobody can tell you why it happens, we can just point out to some things that are sub-optimal, for example, you are using a network with sigmoid activations, and that will just not perform as well as a modern neural network with ReLUs.

Comment: ok so there isnt any errors in the code? just the method used is sub optimal? still doesnt explain why the accuracy decreases with more training data

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add more training data. Because 10 image are less to train a neural network. A neural networks needs **more** data to learn. That will surely increase your models accuracy.

Comment: thats what i thought. but when i train with more than 40 images it just guesses 3 every time. the accuracy gets worse?